# Effects: On "insert" or "on-line"

Tags: microphone, mixer, eq

I'm not sure how's it called. I use an EQ for my microphone. I have two options how to plug it:

```
Microphone -> MIC IN -> Insert OUT -> EQ unit -> Insert IN ->
Microphone -> EQ unit -> MIC IN -> Skip Insert
```

(of course, `Insert OUT&IN` is one plug only). I don't know which is a better option. Should I observe any quality difference? Are there any precautions to be considered? Is any of the options significantly more convenient for some reason?

My setup:

- Mixer YAMAHA MG102C
- Microphone SHURE PG58 (will be upgraded to something better soon)
- Equalizer DOD SR430 Qx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably want to use the insert so the signal passes through the preamp on your mixer before hitting the equalizer.

Comment: Well, there _are_ XLR inputs on the EQ, but as I've just read in the documentation, they expect the same input/output levels as the TS ones. So this seems to be correct, thanks.